# Python - Get Request with Cookies

Tags: python, json, rest, cookies

I've got a puzzling requests that I do not seem able to dig myself out of, despite several attempts.

Context / Workflow:
1. Logging to a webservice
2. Make a Get request
3. Obtain JSoN

Issue:
- JSON obtained by going via browser is different (read: has more data) than the one obtained via my code

My code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers = {'Accept': 'application/json; indent=4', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}            
        secret = {
                 "client_id": "xxx",
                 "client_secret": "yyy"
               }
        datas = json.dumps(secret)
        url = 'https://XXXX.yyy/sign_in'
        response = s.post(url, data=json.dumps(secret), headers=s.headers, verify=False)
        print (s.headers)
        print(response)
```

This part works OK, returns me a cookie, which I save on

```
ck = s.cookies.get_dict()
```

I then need to make a Get request with the cookies saved after successful login

```
url = 'https://give.me/tests'
        print ("Connecting to: " + url)
        # here we do our get, passing the cookies
        response = s.get(url, cookies=ck, verify=False)
        data = response.text
        # print (s.headers) # is OK, returns 200
        # print(data)
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(data)
        return 0
```

Expected Result:

```
"phase": {
"type": "phase",
"activity_level": null,
"logical_name": "phase.test_manual.obsolete",
"name": "Obsolete",
"index": 4,
"id": "phase.test_manual.obsolete"
},
```

Actual Result:

```
        "phase": {
            "type": "phase",
            "id": "phase.test_manual.obsolete"
        },
```

Documentation, in case I'm doing something wrong functionally:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes in API calls you need to specify which all values you want in response, see if that is the case with this service. also share the link to the documentation if possible.

Comment: ck = s.cookies.get_dict(), now `ck` holds a key value pairs which makes cookie. However, while making GET call, you may need to select required key/value from the cookie dict `ck`.  Try "print("cookie=%s" %(ck))" to get the list of items in dict. Now, try using only required item form `ck`. Perhaps, you should be using "sessionID" kinds.

Comment: Thanks. I had similar doubt and so I also tried to pass the key:value pairs of the cookie. Same result, sadly.

Comment: Documentation, see if accessible: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/octane/en/latest/API/Developer_Help.htm#API/Authenticate.htm%3FTocPath%3DThe%2520REST%25C2%25A0API%7CHow%2520to...%7C_____1